# Error in match.arg(mvnTest) : 'arg' must be of length 1

Tags: r

Hi – I wish to run a CFA in r, currently checking off all the assumptions. I ran into problems when applying the following function:

```
mvn(vdata_clean1, subset = 'NULL', mvnTest = c("mardia", "hz", "royston"), 
covariance = TRUE, tol = 1e-25, alpha = 0.5, scale = FALSE, desc = TRUE, 
transform = "none", R = 1000, 
univariateTest = c("SW"), univariatePlot = c("qq", "persp", "contour"), 
multivariateOutlierMethod = "none", bc = FALSE, bcType = "rounded", 
showOutliers = FALSE, showNewData = FALSE)
```

I get this error below:

```
Error in match.arg(mvnTest) : 'arg' must be of length 1
```

Any ideas what I can do to run to function successfully?
Grateful for any advice :)

Comment: You need to post a reproducible example.  You didn't even say which package you found `mvn` in.

Comment: Having installed the newest version (R 3.6.1), I have installed the following package: install.packages("MVN").

The data set I am using (vdata_clean1) only contains the variables I am using for the CFA (no factor variables). 

Does this clarify my problem? Is there any additional info that is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for the `mvnTest` argument says: "select one of the MVN tests."  You can't do three tests in one call.  You'll need to call the function three times, once with each test type.

You may have been confused by the help page, which lists `mvnTest = c("mardia", "hz", "royston", "dh", "energy")`. It is a convention in R to list all possibilities, even though only one selection is allowed.  You can't tell this just by looking at the usage, you need to read the rest of the help page (or recognize the error message).

I believe you'll run into the same problem with `univariatePlot`.